# Convert AnyObject to an Int

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to convert a `anyObject` to an `Int`. Here's my code:

```
println(currentObject[0])
println(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(currentObject[0]))
```

> 2
>   
> Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`<Swift.AnyObject>`

I'm trying to convert `currentObject[0]` to an `Int`. Here's what I tried:

```
let num: Int = currentObjec[0] as! Int
```

When I run the app, I get the following error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x103c93c50) to 'NSNumber' (0x103535b88)

When I try this: `currentObject[0].toInt()`

I get an error saying

> 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'toInt()'

The only way I'm able to make it work, is to do the following:

```
let numStr = currentObject[0] as! String
let num: Int = numStr.toInt()!
```

Is there a simpler way to do it? (Without having to first convert it to a `String`.)

Comment: How did you created/declared currentObject ?

Comment: I got it from an SQLite database as integer PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Can you tell me how you declare that data structure ? I mean something like var currentobject : [AnyObject] ?

Comment: The "only way" is the right way. There is no simpler way because the type of `currentObject[0]` **is** `String`

Comment: It seems that `currentObject[0]` is an `NSString`, so `let numStr = currentObject[0].integerValue` should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the error message

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x103c93c50) to 'NSNumber' (0x103535b88)

you can conclude that `currentObject[0]` is actually an `NSString`.
In that case you can simply convert it with

```
let numStr = currentObject[0].integerValue
```

But note that this will crash if the array element is not an `NSString`.

Comment: hi martin, if there is no error message, how to convert `[Anyobject]?` to Int?